# How to make Bluepill restart Resque workers only after reaching a safe status

Tags: resque, bluepill

Let's say this is my worker:

```
class FooWorker
  @queue = :foo

  def self.perform
    User.all.each do |u|
      ...
      Do Long Operations (Unsafe to kill)
      ...

      # Here it's safe to break the worker and restart
    end
  end
end
```

I'm enqueing this with Resque Scheduler and this is my Bluepill conf:

```
...
app.process(process_name) do |process|
  process.group         = "resque"
  process.start_command = "rake environment resque:work QUEUE=foo RAILS_ENV=production"
  ...
  process.stop_signals  = [:quit, 5.seconds, :term, 1.minute, :kill]
  process.daemonize     = true

  process.start_grace_time = 30.seconds
  process.stop_grace_time  = 80.seconds

  process.monitor_children do |child_process|
    child_process.stop_command = "kill -QUIT {{PID}}"

    child_process.checks :mem_usage, :every => 30.seconds, :below => 500.megabytes, :times => [3,4], :fires => :stop
  end
end
....
```

I'd like to make Bluepill or Resque wait until it reaches the "safe" block to restart or shut down. How to achieve this?

Comment: Are your long operations something that could be put into a database transaction, so that if killed they leave the system in a clean state?  Not the answer you're looking for, but perhaps this is an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

1) Set resque to kill children gracefully on TERM/INT with [`new_kill_child`](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque/worker.rb#L444) method by setting `TERM_CHILD` and `RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT` env variables on start:

```
process.start_command = "rake environment resque:work QUEUE=foo RAILS_ENV=production TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=20.0"
```

Default value for `RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT` is [4 seconds](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque/tasks.rb#L21).

This will make resque send TERM signal to child, wait for `RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT` and if child is still running, kill it. Be sure to

a) set this timeout large enough for your critical section to end,

b) configure Bluepill TERM timeout in `process.stop_signals` to be a bit larger than `RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT` not to kill worker while it waits for child process to end critical section.

2) Handle TERM signal in child process to stop gracefully:

```
class FooWorker
  class << self
    attr_accessor :stop
  end

  @queue = :foo
  def self.perform
    User.all.each do |u|
      ...
      Do Long Operations (Unsafe to kill)
      ...

      # Here it's safe to break the worker and restart
      return if FooWorker.stop
    end
  end
end

trap('TERM') do
  FooWorker.stop = true
end
```